# Writing Builder pattern in Scala while hiding case class direct access

Tags: scala, design-patterns, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Let's assume this builder:

```
@NodeEntity
case class Meeting(@Indexed creator: String, @Indexed title: String, @Indexed description: String,
                 @Indexed activityType: String, @Indexed startSchedule: Date, @Indexed endSchedule: Date,
                 @Indexed place: String, @Indexed maxParticipants: Int) {

  @GraphId private var _id: Long = _

  private def this() {
    this("unknown", "no title", "no description", "no activity type", new Date(), new Date(), "no place", 0)
    //dummy values in order to satisfy Scala's no-arg constructor syntax (required by Spring-Data)
  }
}

object Meeting {

  def builder(): PossibleMeeting = PossibleMeeting()

  case class PossibleMeeting(creator: String = "", title: String = "", description: String = "",
                           activityType: String = "", schedule: (Date, Date) = (new Date(), new Date()),
                           place: String = "", maxParticipants: Int = 0) {

    def withCreator(creator: String) = {
        this.copy(creator = creator)
      }

      def withTitle(title: String) = {
        this.copy(title = title)
      }

      def withDescription(description: String) = {
        this.copy(description = description)
      }

      def withActivityType(activityType: String) = {
        this.copy(activityType = activityType)
      }

      def withSchedule(schedule: (Date, Date)) = {
        this.copy(schedule = schedule)
      }

      def withPlace(place: String) = {
        this.copy(place = place)
      }

      def withMaxParticipants(maxParticipants: Int) = {
        this.copy(maxParticipants = maxParticipants)
      }

      def build(validator: PossibleMeetingValidator) = {
        this.toMeeting(validator)
      }

    def toMeeting(possibleMeetingValidator: PossibleMeetingValidator): ValidationNEL[MeetingValidationError, Meeting] =
      (possibleMeetingValidator.checkForNonEmpty("creator", creator, "Creator must not be empty") |@|
        possibleMeetingValidator.checkForNonEmpty("title", title, "Title must not be empty") |@|
        possibleMeetingValidator.checkForNonEmpty("description", description, "Description must not be empty") |@|
        possibleMeetingValidator.checkForNonEmpty("activityType", activityType, "Activity type must not be empty") |@|
        possibleMeetingValidator.checkForEndScheduleConsistency("endSchedule", schedule._1, schedule._2, "Schedule is not consistent since endSchedule date is anterior to startSchedule date") |@|
        possibleMeetingValidator.checkForNonEmpty("place", place, "Place must not be empty"))(Meeting(_, _, _, _, schedule._1, _, _, maxParticipants))

  }
```

The annotation `@NodeEntity` is used by *Spring-Data-Neo4j* in order to save the object as a graph node.

I would like to force client to use this call syntax to create a `Meeting`:

```
Meeting.builder().
          withCreator(creator).
          withTitle(title).withDescription(description).
          withActivityType(activityType).
          withSchedule(schedule).withPlace(place).
          withMaxParticipants(maxParticipants).build(PossibleMeetingValidator())
```

instead of the risked direct way:

```
Meeting(creator, title, description, activityType, schedule, place, maxParticipants)
```

I tried the famous trick of extending a `case class`, here `Meeting` by a sealed trait and make `Meeting` private. This link shows a sample: [Hiding case class allowing leaking](http://gist.github.com/travisbrown/5008062).

However, with this solution, *Spring-Data* throws an error informing that `Meeting` must have a public constructor(meaning a public class/case class).

Is there another way of hiding case class from external direct use so that Spring-Data wouldn't complain about access? It seems very hard, if not impossible but...it would be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if I understand correctly this boils down to have a constructor that spring can call, but scala code cannot.
One (ugly) solution I see is to make the cosntructor private to the `Meeting` singleton. This will prevent scala code (other than the singleton) to directly instantiate it.
On the other hand, because java does not support the concept of "scoped private", the constructor is actually public from the point of view of java code. In particular, when accessing the constructor through java reflection, the constructor is seen as public and can be called. This means that spring should have no problem instantiating `Meeting`, but at the same time scala code won't be able to instantiate it directly. Just what you want.

So all you have to do is this (note the `private` keyword before the parameter list):

```
@NodeEntity
case class Meeting private[Meeting] (@Indexed creator: String, @Indexed title: String, @Indexed description: String,
             @Indexed activityType: String, @Indexed startSchedule: Date, @Indexed endSchedule: Date,
             @Indexed place: String, @Indexed maxParticipants: Int) {
 ...
```

This should work as expected, though it's a bit gross to rely on the imperfect mapping of scala code to the JVM model.

Another cleaner alternative would be to teach spring how to instantitate your class, using a custom factory that calls `Metting.builder`. I won't comment further on this solution as I have no experience with spring. However from a quick glance it seems that the following is relevant:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean

Comment: You're right: making `case class` private well works but would tightly couple framework needs (in this case Spring) to scala code. I prefer to set up a bean-factory and implement the sealed trait trick. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, I can't count on the Spring's FactoryBean feature. Indeed, my client code constructs an object in several steps (using methods `withXXX`, that's one of the main advantages of a builder). Spring's feature allows to configure a static method to be called (`Meeting.Builder()`) but returning a `Meeting` in one step (until the end of the method)! As my concept is to not construct a `Meeting` before its validation, I can't use this Spring feature. Luckily, private case class principle well works :)

Comment: There is a way of providing SDN with custom instantiators. See: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j-aspects/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/aspects/support/NodeEntityInstantiationTests.java Look at the config and PersonCreator used there.